# How can I synchronize two quartz2 components of two different camel contexts?

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, jbossfuse

I have two different camel contexts having a quartz2 component that define a job with theirs cron. I want to synchronize this two different quartzes so that the second one runs after the completion of the first. Following there is an example of code

```
<camelContext id="context_1">    
     <route id="route_1">
         <from uri="quartz2:timer_1?cron=20+*+*+*+*+?&amp;stateful=true"/>
         ....
     </route>
</camelContext>

<camelContext id="context_2">    
      <route id="route_2">
          <from uri="quartz2:timer_2?cron=30+*+*+*+*+?&amp;stateful=true"/>
          ....
      </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: The chaining of quartz jobs is a challenge and the syntax of the quartz component in Camel doesn't address this particular functionality, let alone across contexts! See the Quartz FAQs on "chaining" jobs, and consider having those jobs call the routes in the individual contexts.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the "run after completion" functionality, try with [VM Component](http://camel.apache.org/vm.html). VM works across different contexts that runs in the *same* JVM.

```
<camelContext id="context_1">    
    <route id="route_1">
        <from uri="quartz2:timer_1?cron=20+*+*+*+*+?&amp;stateful=true"/>
        ....
        <to uri="vm:startAfter" />
    </route>
</camelContext>

<camelContext id="context_2">    
    <route id="route_2">
        <from uri="vm:startAfter"/>
        ....
    </route>
</camelContext>
```